# SwiftUI - Canvas exceeding screen width - App Rejected

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

My app was rejected twice on submission to the app store based on an issue where the login screen is exceeding the boundaries of an iPad display.  I have tried to replicate the issue but cannot on the simulator or on a physical iPad

Apple sent me the following response

```
From Apple
4. Design: Preamble
Guideline 4.0 - Design

We noticed that the login screen of your app was still crowded or laid out in a way that made it difficult to use your app.
We launched the app on iPad (6th generation) running iOS 13.1.3 on Wifi.

Next Steps
To resolve this issue, please revise your app to ensure that the content and controls on the screen are easy to read and interact with.

Resources
For more information, please review the following resources on the iOS Developer Center page:

   - UI Do's and Don'ts
   - iOS Human Interface Guidelines
   - UIKit

Please see attached screenshot for details.
```

[image: Clipped login screen]

I cannot replicate this.  Here's my code:

Login.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct Login: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @ObservedObject private var kGuardian = KeyboardGuardian(textFieldCount: KeyboardGuardian.KeyboardSlots.count.rawValue)

    @State var email: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var loading = false
    @State var error = false


    func getUser () {
        session.listen()
    }

    func signIn () {
        loading = true
        error = false
        session.signIn(email: email, password: password) { (result, error) in
            self.loading = false
            if error != nil {
                self.error = true
            } else {
                self.email = ""
                self.password = ""
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("Cloud Pager")
                .resizable()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fill)
                .padding()

            Text("Cloud Pager")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .bold()
                .padding(Edge.Set.bottom, 30)

            Spacer()

            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Email")
                    .foregroundColor(email.isEmpty ? .white : .black)
                    .fontWeight(email.isEmpty ? .regular : .bold)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    .offset(y: email.isEmpty ? 0 : -30)

                TextField("", text:$email)
                    .background(Color.clear)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                    .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
            }
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 3.0, alignment: .bottom)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(.bottom, 40)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
                .padding(.trailing, 10)

            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Password")
                    .foregroundColor(password.isEmpty ? .white : .black)
                    .fontWeight(password.isEmpty ? .regular : .bold)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    .offset(y: password.isEmpty ? 0 : -30)
                SecureField("", text:$password)
                    .background(Color.clear)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .textContentType(.password)
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
            }
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 3.0, alignment: .bottom)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .padding(.bottom, 50)
                .padding(.leading, 10)
                .padding(.trailing, 10)

            VStack {
                Button(action: signIn) {
                    HStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Spacer()
                        if loading {
                            ActivityIndicator()
                        } else {
                            Text("Sign In")
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                                .bold()
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }.padding().background(Color.white).cornerRadius(30.0)
            }
            .padding(Edge.Set.bottom, 8)
        }
        .padding()
        .background(Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        .onAppear(perform: getUser)
        .offset(y: kGuardian.slide).animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
    }
}

struct ActivityIndicator: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        let v = UIActivityIndicatorView()

        return v
    }

    func updateUIView(_ activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: Context) {
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    }
}

struct Login_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Login()
            .environmentObject(SessionStore())
    }
}
```

On every iPad simulator I run the app on (and a physical 6th Generation iPad) I cannot replicate the above screenshot.  Mine always look like this:

[image: Non clipped screenshot]

Can anyone figure out what is going on here.  My app settings are set to Portrait only on iPhone and iPad devices

Info.plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIRequiresFullScreen</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It would be nice if you create a minimal project and add a link to it instead of this dependent code.

Comment: I have the entire project on github but the repo is private due to it including firebase config files.

Comment: There is no need for entire project. just his page linked to static data.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for.

Comment: The entire answer is just changing two characters. fi**ll** -> fi**t**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with the image configuration. You should add the following modifier to it:

```
.scaledToFit()
```

or **just** change the content mode to **fit**

```
.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
```

**Before** -> **After**

[image: Before After]

Note that **everything** can not be resizable and it is always better to make some of them fixed size.

### Suggestion:

for pages like this, put everything in a container and give it `maxWidth` and `maxHeight`. You don't want your design to scale to fill *entire* 100 inch TV showing your app using second Screen option, do you?

**Note 2**: The image you are using is *very close* to **copyrighted** icon's from Apple, maybe next time apple reject your app because of that. Take care.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  How do you get the simulator to scale outside the canvas?  I want to test your answer but I cannot replicate the issue in the first place.

Comment: Copy this code (in the question) in a brand new project and fix all errors to make it independent.

Comment: Created a new project.  Dropped in the code and fixed errors.  Compiled and ran on iPad 6th gen and iPhone 11 simulators.  Neither exceeded the canvas like yours `https://imgur.com/a/0f2Llhp`

Comment: Sorted it.  The reason it wasn't showing on my simulator is that I was running xcode 11 and not 11.1 as the 11.1 install was having errors.  Deleted install and upgraded to 11.1 which showed the extended canvas as yours did.  Answer is perfect, cheers.

Comment: I will award bounty when it lets me (10 hours)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things.

It is the .aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fill) that extends the top level VStack beyond the bounds of of the screen.

[image: image pushing vstack out of bounds]

So you have to change it to:

```
.aspectRatio(contentMode: ContentMode.fit)
```

Which seems to do the trick:

[image: image drawn correctly]

But, if you run it in the simulator and rotate the iPad a few times you will notice that your blue background is not redrawing correctly:

[[image: background problem[3]]

To fix that you can wrap everything in a ZStack:

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.blue
        VStack {
            Image("Cloud Pager")
            // etc
        }
        .padding()
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        .onAppear(perform: getUser)
        .offset(y: kGuardian.slide).animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5))
    }   .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```